# How to correct NodeJS Cannot find installed package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-routing

Just went through the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial for Angular2 and was really enjoying the NPM system then I went to add my first package.

I added "eveonlinejs": "^2.0.0" to my package.json and ran "npm install"

The package installed and the folder is present in node_modules.

Running my server however results in.

```
app/eveapi.service.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'eveonlinejs'.
```

The line in question is

```
import { eveonlinejs } from 'eveonlinejs';
```

From my research I believe that the import should hit the package.json in the "node_modules/eveonlinejs" directory and see the "main" property which is set.

I have tried deleting clearing the NPM cache and reinstalling the node_modules folder.

I have also tried using a require statement to point into the directory but then I get a missing module for "sax" which is installed inside the "eveonlinejs" directory.

**Update:**

Thanks to @nem035 I've gotten a bit futher and have stopped using *import* however found I was getting a 404 error when using *require*.

I was able to get a step further by adding this code:

**systemjs.config.js**

```
'eveonlinejs': 'npm:eveonlinejs/lib/eveonline.js'
```

Which got me back to having errors with "sax." I found that Sax has, for some reason, moved out of the eveonlinejs folder up to the root node_modules folder.

```
'sax': 'npm:sax/lib/sax.js'
```

This corrected the Sax issue however gave me all this!

```
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/eveonlinejs/lib/client 404 (Not Found)
dashboard:17 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/eveonlinejs/lib/client
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/eveonlinejs/lib/cache/cache 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/eveonlinejs/lib/cache/file 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/eveonlinejs/lib/cache/memory 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/stream 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/string_decoder 404 (Not Found)
```

Everyone of these I fix reveals another‽ If this is what NodeJS is like then I'm out. Haha!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is remove the `{}` around your import.

```
import { eveonlinejs } from 'eveonlinejs';
// ----^-------------^-------------------- Remove the curly braces
```

You probably want this

```
import eveonlinejs from 'eveonlinejs';
```

The reason is because wrapping `{}` around the import tries to extract a named export from the file, but you want the whole library.

```
// import { eveonlinejs } from 'eveonlinejs' expects export code as
export {
  eveonlinejs
}
```

When you leave out the braces, the `import` tries to extract the default export.

```
// import eveonlinejs from 'eveonlinejs' expects import as
export default eveonlinejs
```

Now, if you're using the version of eveonlinejs that's is currently on [github](https://github.com/MichaelErmer/eveonlinejs/blob/master/lib/eveonline.js), this might not work depending on how you're transpiling your modules (and how this process deals with `module.exports`).

The safe way would be to just use require:

```
var eveonlinejs = require('eveonlinejs');
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the brackets but I'm still not able to get it working. 

Tried without brackets and then tried using "require" method.

With require I get
`(404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/eveonlinejs`

Which seems very strange to me.

Comment: You're welcome mate, glad to help out if I can. Based on what you said, the `require` approach is working, now you have a second issue which is that the server doesn't handle the `/evenonlinejs` route.

Comment: Seems you answered my question with "You can't do what you're trying to do." Which is a solid answer but I can't find anything on what to do with a "requirejs 404 error". I honestly had that 404 come up hours ago and kept trucking away because "that can't be right!"

Comment: The 404 error has nothing to do with `require`. The issue is that your server doesn't handle http requests on `your-servers-url/eveonlonejs` url. The fact that the last part of the url and your npm package have the same name doesn't mean the two are related. In fact, it's most likely they have nothing to do with each other. Make sure you're server's routing logic includes the route in question.

Comment: That 404 only appears with the require line on the page. Would you mind taking a look at the update I posted above?

Comment: @JasonTucker are you using any particular framework besides NodeJS? What about on the client?

Comment: I went through the Angular2 tutorials. [Tutorial1](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and [Tutorial2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with angular2 but the issue seems related to angular routing and not NodeJS. I would suggest tagging your question with [tag:angular2] so users with angular knowledge get to see it. You can also [read](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) about the angular router because most likely you didn't setup the router properly. [Seems like a common issue](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular2%20404)